# identify this play / teleplay: all of creation was a higher being's homework assignment

Tags: identification-request

I remember seeing it on television some time ago, but my IMDB searches are failing me. The basic plot was that we are watching what is essentially a dissertation defense of a higher being who created the universe. He carefully groomed an exemplar person in this universe to be judged, but through some accident a random midwestern telephone lineman winds up being the representative.

EDIT: While I saw it on television, I do distinctly remember that it was a production of a stage play. It was in English, and was an American production. It was at least 20, perhaps 30 years ago. It was effectively a one-room / set production with, I believe a total of either 4 or 5 characters: The telephone lineman, his wife, the "student" and either one or two faculty inquisitors.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Can you please add a few more details, such as the language of the (tele)play, when you saw it (year) and where (country)? Please be aware that this is a site about **literature**, so questions to identify teleplays that do not exist outside the world of TV might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Sounds quite intriguing!